# Variadic template doesn't recognise a constexpr function

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, type-safety, constexpr

I'm trying to initialize some C++ array at compile time but I got a weird g++ error. Here is the smallest chunk of code I've been able to get which reproduce the error:

```
#include <array>

template<typename Ar, int... Vals>
constexpr Ar Map(typename Ar::value_type /*int*/ fun(int)) 
{ return {{ fun(Vals)... }}; }

constexpr int add(int i) { return i + 1; }

constexpr auto b = Map<std::array<int, 2>, 1, 2>(add);
```

The compiler is complaining

```
bug.cpp:8:53:   in constexpr expansion of ‘Map<std::array<int, 2ul>, {1, 2}>(add)’
bug.cpp:4:80: error: expression ‘add’ does not designate a constexpr function
 constexpr Ar Map(typename Ar::value_type /*int*/ fun(int)) { return {{ fun(Vals)... }}; }
```

This happens both with g++ 4.7.1 and 4.9.0 20130520 (experimental). Note that
if I replace `typename Ar::value_type` by `int` (see the comment) in the definition of 
`Map`, everything works as expected. Is this a bug of am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is [Bug 52892 - Function pointer loses constexpr qualification](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52892) .

Comment: It does compile when `typename Ar::value_type` is replaced with `int` though

Comment: @mirk: Read the bug report: `The template parameter in your example has similar effects as a typedef. Both use cases should not invalidate the constexpr character.` It happens when using with a `typedef` or template parameter.

Comment: Thank for the answer ! Debugging those code is still a nightmare.